# index out of range, when using pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I give up.  I have been trying to solve this "Target Invocation Exception" error thrown whenever i iterate through the rows in my gridview.

Problem: I am trying to iterate through gridview rows from user input, accepting row numbers to change the social worker assigned to that row. for eg. row 3 to row 4, assign a social worker from the dropdownlist names.

[image]

The error does not happen when i don't use pagination.  Everything works fine, but when i use pagination, that's when i get the TargetInvocationException when stepping through the code.

[image]

The last page, after load, shows, "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.". 
[image]
[image]

I even tried to disable the pagination during this click event, but doesn't seem to work.

```
var fromCount = Convert.ToInt32(txtFrom.Text)
var toCount = Convert.ToInt32(txtTo.Text);
for (int rows=fromCount; rows <= toCount; rows++)
{
  GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
  int row = rows - 1;
  var pi = db.PatientInfos.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PatientID == Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Text));
  pi.UserName = userId;
 }
 db.SubmitChanges();
 BindPatientList();
```

So is there a way for me to fix this, having pagination on my gridview, and also go to the next page while iterating and assigning the social worker to the next page's rows ?

All I'm trying to do is to access the 2nd page rows.  Any help or pointers to where I am going wrong, will be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could we get that third image with the error?

Answer (score 0):

`GridView.Rows` contains only rows that are displayed on current page. You cannot access rows that are displayed on other pages through this property. Instead, try accessing these rows through the DataSource object that you assigned to `GridView.DataSource` property.

Comment: I am binding the gridview's datasource through the search result, which is a different method, and i am not sure how to achieve this.  Currently, i solved this by making the grid scrollable..but still would like to get a solution for paging.